# python - a simple switch statement IS too much to ask for... trying to pull conditional values - newbie needs direction

Tags: python, pandas

I have a situation where I am looking to set unit and extended pricing on a quantity of components on a BOM - there are 1x, 10x and 100+ prices from a vendor as in the example below the kit quantity drives the unit pricing. I have the spreadsheet in a df but am having an awful time pulling the correct value (1x, 10x, 100x) into the unit price field

```
1X     10X      100X    Qty     Kit_Qty   unit     ext
0.1    0.062    0.0276  1       7
0.11   0.08     0.0376  1       7
0.1    0.062    0.0276  15      105
0.16   0.117    0.065   15      105
0.1    0.035    0.0158  3       21
0.1    0.055    0.0243  3       21
```

The above example has 2 items that are qty 7 - the 1x values should be pulled into the unit price field. the next has 105 - the 100x price should be selected - the last has 21 - the 10x price... I've generated boolean maps, etc can't seem to map the values to the outputs with the correct conditionals. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using boolean expressions as integers.  True is 1, False is 0.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
[0.1, 0.062, 0.0276, 1, 7],
[0.11, 0.08, 0.0376, 1, 7],
[0.1, 0.062, 0.0276, 15, 105],
[0.16, 0.117, 0.065, 15, 105],
[0.1, 0.035, 0.0158, 3, 21],
[0.1, 0.055, 0.0243, 3, 21]
]

cols = "1X 10X 100X Qty Kit_Qty".split()

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
print(df)

df['unit'] = \
        df['1X'] * (df['Kit_Qty']<10) +\
        df['10X'] * (df['Kit_Qty']<100) * (df['Kit_Qty']>=10) +\
        df['100X'] * (df['Kit_Qty']>=100)
print(df)
df['ext'] = df['Qty'] * df['unit']
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     1X    10X    100X  Qty  Kit_Qty
0  0.10  0.062  0.0276    1        7
1  0.11  0.080  0.0376    1        7
2  0.10  0.062  0.0276   15      105
3  0.16  0.117  0.0650   15      105
4  0.10  0.035  0.0158    3       21
5  0.10  0.055  0.0243    3       21
     1X    10X    100X  Qty  Kit_Qty    unit
0  0.10  0.062  0.0276    1        7  0.1000
1  0.11  0.080  0.0376    1        7  0.1100
2  0.10  0.062  0.0276   15      105  0.0276
3  0.16  0.117  0.0650   15      105  0.0650
4  0.10  0.035  0.0158    3       21  0.0350
5  0.10  0.055  0.0243    3       21  0.0550
     1X    10X    100X  Qty  Kit_Qty    unit    ext
0  0.10  0.062  0.0276    1        7  0.1000  0.100
1  0.11  0.080  0.0376    1        7  0.1100  0.110
2  0.10  0.062  0.0276   15      105  0.0276  0.414
3  0.16  0.117  0.0650   15      105  0.0650  0.975
4  0.10  0.035  0.0158    3       21  0.0350  0.105
5  0.10  0.055  0.0243    3       21  0.0550  0.165
```

Comment: thank you... I was banging my head on the table - couldn't see the forest through the trees...